# The type or namespace name 'Project name' could not be found

Tags: sitecore-rocks

I'm currently following the online Sitecore developer formation (official) and i'm unfortunately having troubles to go any further due to a compilation error while trying to preview an item.

Basically, all what i'm trying to do is, binding a component statically, as explained in the lab.
In order to do that, i created a controller, a model class and a view :

Controller:

```
using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Website.Models;

namespace Website.Controllers
{
    public class EventIntroController : Controller
    {
        // GET: EventIntro
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(CreateModel());
        }
        private static EventIntro CreateModel()
        {
            var item = RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem;
            var eventIntro = new EventIntro()
            {
                Heading = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item,"ContentHeading")),
                EventImage = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Event Image","mw=400")),
                Highlights = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Highlights")),
                Intro = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, "ContentIntro")),
                StartDate = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Start Date")),
                Duration = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Duration")),
                Difficulty = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Difficulty Level")),
            };
            return eventIntro;
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Website.Models
{
    public class EventIntro
    {
        public EventIntro() { }
        public HtmlString Heading { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Intro { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Body { get; set; }
        public HtmlString EventImage { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Highlights { get; set; }
        public HtmlString StartDate { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Duration { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Difficulty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Website.Models.EventIntro
<header>
    <h1>@Model.Heading</h1>
</header>
<!-- [Event Details] -->
<div class="well">
    <p class="text-muted">@Model.StartDate</p>
    <p class="text-muted">Duration: @Model.Duration</p>
    <span class="text-muted">Difficulty:</span>
    <div class="difficulty-circle">
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" id=group-2-0 value=10 />
        <label class=red for=group-2-0></label>
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="group-2" id=group-2-1 value=9 />
        <label class=red for=group-2-1></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" id=group-2-2 value=8 />
        <label class=red for=group-2-2></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" id=group-2-3 value=7 />
        <label class=yellow for=group-2-3></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" id=group-2-4 value=6 />
        <label class=yellow for=group-2-4></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" id=group-2-5 value=5 />
        <label class=yellow for=group-2-5></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" id=group-2-6 value=4 />
        <label class=green for=group-2-6></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" id=group-2-7 value=3 />
        <label class=green for=group-2-7></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" id=group-2-8 value=2 />
        <label class=green for=group-2-8></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" id=group-2-9 value=1 />
        <label class=green for=group-2-9></label>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- [/Event Details] -->
<!-- [Event Content] -->
<div class="lead">
    @Model.Body
</div>
<div class="article image">
    @Model.EventImage
</div>
<div class="highlights">
    <h4>Trip @Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("Highlights")</h4>
    @Model.Highlights
</div>
<!-- [/Event Content] -->
```

I also created a new rendering in the layout/renderings folder of my Sitecore instance(through Sitcore Rocks). Then in another view, i call it this way:

```
 @*@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/Renderings/TAC/Events/Event Intro")*@
```

With the help of Sitecore Rocks, i simply synchronized the folders containing all those files copied above and i get the following error:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
> required to service this request. Please review the following specific
> error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Website'
> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 26:     using System.Web.Optimization; Line 27:     using
> System.Web.Routing; Line 28:     using Website; Line 29:      Line 30:
>
> ## line 1 "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ssd.tac.local\Website\Views\TAC\Events\Layouts\Events.cshtml"
>
> Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
> ASP.NET
> Files\root\a832d361\1901ffbf\App_Web_events.cshtml.9351e6fa.xdrjtduy.0.cs
> Line: 28

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you copy the dll to the bin folder? have you checked if it is there?

Comment: Agreed, it looks like you haven't deployed your assembly to the web application. The dll that your project produces should be in the Website/bin folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was my problem... I don't understand why but in the video demo. The guy had not moved that dll to the bin folder of the sitecore instance. Reason why i didn't do it....

Comment: I think you need to use this code to call a controller rendering in razor (cshtml) @Html.Sitecore().Controller("EventInfo", "EventInfo")